# Numbering some integer partitions

Tags: haskell, combinatorics

These trees represent the integer partitions of `n <= 5` with at most `m = 3` parts.

```
1            2                 3          4      5
|          /   \             /   \        |
|         /     \           /     \       |
|        /       \         /       \      |
1,1     2,1      2,2     3,1      3,2    4,1
|        |        |       |
|        |        |       |
|        |        |       |
1,1,1   2,1,1    2,2,1  3,1,1
```

Let's enumerate them from top to bottom and left to right:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 10 11
12 13 14 15
```

I need a list `D` such that `D!!i` is, if `P` is the partition numbered by `i`, the number of the partition `P ++ [1]`. That is, for this example,

- `D!!1 = 6`, because `(1,1)` has number 6
- `D!!2 = 7` because `(2,1)` has number 7.
- `D!!3 = 9` because `(3,1)` has number 9.
- `D!!4 = 11` because `(4,1)` has number 11.
- `D!!5 = "nothing"` because there's no child `(5,1)`.
- `D!!6 = 12` because `(1,1)` has number 6 and `(1,1,1)` has number 12.

And so on, `D!!7 = 13`, `D!!8 = 14`, and `D!!9 = 15`.

I have absolutely no idea how to start. I know SO is not a code writing service but I'm asking only for any hints.

---

## EDIT

Here is an attempt.

```
dico' :: Int -> Int -> Seq (Maybe Int)
dico' m n = go 1 S.empty
  where
  go :: Int -> Seq (Maybe Int) -> Seq (Maybe Int)
  go k d'
    | k == n-1 = d'
    | otherwise = go (k+1) (inner 0 [0] [m] [m] 0 d')
      where
      inner :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> Int -> Seq (Maybe Int) -> Seq (Maybe Int)
      inner i a b c end d
        | i >= length a = d -- what is the terminating condition here ?
        | otherwise = if b!!i > 0
          then let l = min (b!!i) (c!!i) in
          let dd = d |> (Just $ end+1) in
          inner (i+1) (a ++ [end + 1 .. end + l]) (b ++ map (\x -> b!!i - x) [1 .. l]) (c ++ [1 .. l]) (end + l) dd
          else inner (i+1) a b c end (d |> Nothing)
```

It works except that the result is too long. I don't find the appropriate terminating condition of the inner loop.

```
> dico' 5 3
fromList [Just 1,Just 6,Just 7,Just 9,Just 11,Nothing,Just 12,Just 13,Just 14,Just 15,Nothing,Nothing,Just 16,Just 17,Nothing,Nothing,Just 18,Nothing,Nothing]
```

---

## EDIT 2

Ok I get it now. I'm still interested in any improvement.

```
a008284_tabl :: [[Int]]
a008284_tabl = [1] : f [[1]]
  where
  f xss = ys : f (ys : xss)
    where
    ys = map sum (zipWith take [1..] xss) ++ [1]

_P :: Int -> Int -> Int
_P m n = sum (concatMap (take (min m n)) (take m a008284_tabl))

dico' :: Int -> Int -> Seq (Maybe Int)
dico' m n = go 1 S.empty
  where
  pmn = Just $ Just $ _P m n
  go :: Int -> Seq (Maybe Int) -> Seq (Maybe Int)
  go k d'
    | k == n-1 = d'
    | otherwise = go (k+1) (inner 0 [0] [m] [m] 0 d')
      where
      inner :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> Int -> Seq (Maybe Int)
            -> Seq (Maybe Int)
      inner i a b c end d
        | S.lookup (S.length d - 1) d == pmn = d
        | otherwise = let bi = b!!i in
          if bi > 0
            then let l = min bi (c!!i) in
              let dd = d |> (Just $ end+1) in
              let range1l = [1 .. l] in
              inner (i+1) (a ++ [end + 1 .. end + l])
                          (b ++ map (\x -> bi - x) range1l)
                          (c ++ range1l) (end + l) dd
            else inner (i+1) a b c end (d |> Nothing)


> dico' 5 3
fromList [Just 1,Just 6,Just 7,Just 9,Just 11,Nothing,Just 12,Just 13,Just 14,Just 15]
> dico' 10 7
fromList [Just 1,Just 11,Just 12,Just 14,Just 17,Just 21,Just 26,Just 30,Just 33,Just 35,Nothing,Just 36,Just 37,Just 38,Just 40,Just 41,Just 43,Just 46,Just 47,Just 49,Just 52,Just 54,Just 55,Just 57,Just 59,Nothing,Just 60,Just 61,Just 63,Nothing,Just 64,Just 65,Nothing,Just 66,Nothing,Nothing,Just 67,Just 68,Just 69,Just 70,Just 72,Just 73,Just 74,Just 76,Just 77,Just 79,Just 80,Just 81,Just 82,Just 84,Just 85,Nothing,Just 86,Nothing,Just 87,Just 88,Just 89,Just 90,Nothing,Nothing,Just 91,Just 92,Nothing,Nothing,Just 93,Nothing,Nothing,Just 94,Just 95,Just 96,Just 97,Just 98,Just 100,Just 101,Just 102,Just 103,Just 104,Just 105,Nothing,Nothing,Just 106,Just 107,Just 108,Nothing,Just 109,Nothing,Nothing,Just 110,Just 111,Nothing,Nothing,Just 112,Nothing,Nothing,Just 113,Just 114,Just 115,Just 116,Just 117,Nothing,Just 118,Just 119,Just 120,Nothing,Just 121,Nothing,Just 122,Just 123,Nothing,Nothing,Just 124,Nothing,Nothing,Just 125,Just 126,Just 127,Just 128,Nothing,Just 129,Just 130,Nothing,Nothing,Just 131]
```

Comment: Hint: how many items does the subtree of `n` holds?

Comment: Just wondering... this algorithm could apply to any language, so maybe add language agnostic as a tag as well as the algorithm tag. I know a lot of skilled people follow the algorithm tag.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry I don't see a simple formula. But I'm currently at the hospital (for nothing severe) not in good conditions to concentrate...

Comment: The complete procedure seems complicated, but continuing the "hint" above: you could look at each layer individually. The first layer has *n* elements (here *n* is the maximum value for the partition sum). You could state the second layer as: the amount of non-ordered *(a,b)* pairs where *a+b=k*, for *k=2,...,n*. For every even number, that would equal to *k/2* whereas for odd numbers, that'd be *(k-1)/2*, so this sum for *n* equals *2/2+2/2+4/2+4/2+...+n/2*, which you can simplify to *(n/2)^2*, and (n^2-1)/4 for odd numbers. You could do the same for layer 3, but it'll be more complicated

Comment: I would be very much interested though what problem motivated this question. 

You may want to take a look at [Wiki: Compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)), the one you'd find interesting is the non-weak compositions, however, they are ordered, and you don't distinguish (a,b) from (b,a)

Comment: @me9hanics Thanks. The problem was the implementation of an algorithm computing the Jack polynomials. I found the number of trees thanks to OEIS (a008284).